# In Django REST framework's authentication, how do I set the default access scheme to allow all endpoints to not require authentication?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication, django-contrib

I'm using Django 3.2 and djangorestframework==3.12.2.  I recently added this to my settings file because I want to add some secured endpoints to my application ...

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
         'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
         'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
         ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    )
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    # how long the original token is valid for
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(hours=1),

}
```

However, this seems to have caused all my endpoints to require authentication.  For example, I had this view set up in my views.py file

```
class CoopList(APIView):
    """
    List all coops, or create a new coop.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        contains = request.GET.get("contains", "")
        if contains:
            coops = Coop.objects.find(
                partial_name=contains,
                enabled=True
            )
        else:
            partial_name = request.GET.get("name", "")
            enabled_req_param = request.GET.get("enabled", None)
            enabled = enabled_req_param.lower() == "true" if enabled_req_param else None
            city = request.GET.get("city", None)
            zip = request.GET.get("zip", None)
            street = request.GET.get("street", None)
            state = request.GET.get("state", None)
            coop_types = request.GET.get("coop_type", None)
            types_arr = coop_types.split(",") if coop_types else None

            coops = Coop.objects.find(
                partial_name=partial_name,
                enabled=enabled,
                street=street,
                city=city,
                zip=zip,
                state_abbrev=state,
                types_arr=types_arr
            )
        serializer = CoopSearchSerializer(coops, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

accessible in my urls.py file using

```
path('coops/', views.CoopList.as_view()),
```

But now when I try and call that I get the below response

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

I only want certain views/endpoints secured.  How do I make the default that all views are accessible and only specify some views/endpoints to be validated using a provided JWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES'` is conventiently applied to all views, unless manually overridden. In your case **both** listed permissions require the user to be authenticated. FYI, the list is evaluated in an `OR` fashion.

If you want to allow everyone by default and only tighten down specific views, you want to set

`'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny']`

which does not require the user to be authenticated. Then set more strict permissions explicitly on the view (e.g. `permissions_classes = [IsAuthenticated]`) The `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS` can stay as is.

NOTE: It is generally advisable to do it the other way round. It's very easy to accidentally expose an unsecured endpoint like this and potentially create a security breach in your API. The default should be secure and then exceptions should be be manually lifted.

Comment: Regarding your "NOTE: It is generally advisable to do it the other way round", I'm into it, but then how would I specify in each view/method taht I woudl like it to not require authentication?

Comment: for class based views you can set permission class to empty list. permission_classes = [ ] for function based views add the decorator @permission_classes([]). permission_classes is imported from  rest_framework.decorators for FBV

Answer (score 0):

Set the below configuration in settings.py

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
   'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
]
```

For class based views you can set permission class to empty list.

```
class CoopList(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
  
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pass
```

For Function based views add the decorator @permission_classes

```
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes

@permission_classes([])
def CoopList(request, format=None):
    pass
```